# YouTrack on Tomcat 7 using SSL

Tags: ssl, tomcat, mod-proxy, mod-ssl, tomcat7

I have a running [YouTrack](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) instance deployed using Tomcat 7 and it works fine on `http://example.com:8080/youtrack`

Apache is already configured to support SSL for the main domain (I have .pem file). Both `https://example.com` and `http://example.com` are accessible without any problems.

The port 8443 is already used by some other service (`https://example.com:8443` shows me Plesk admin panel).

Now I'd like to set up YouTrack to use `https://youtrack.example.com`

How can I achieve this?

Do I need to configure Tomcat to support SSL (generate separate key etc.),
or just proxy the requests from Apache to Tomcat?

I guess the first step would be to configure YouTrack to be accessible on `https://example.com:8444/youtrack`,
then proxy the requests using Apache's `mod_proxy`.

How can I do this?

My `/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/server.conf` is default, without any changes: http://pastie.org/9385045

My `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh` contains the entry to change the YouTrack default URL:
`-Djetbrains.youtrack.baseUrl=http://youtrack.example.com`

Virtual hosts configuration:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/default
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/default>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

SSL host:

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/default
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/default>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

SSLEngine on


SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/mailserver.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mailserver.pem

#SSLVerifyClient require
#SSLVerifyDepth  10

#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
# MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a better choice over `mod_proxy` would be `mod_jk`.

See [Working with mod_jk](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need configure SSL for tomcat, just use the Apache to proxy the request to `http://example.com:8080/youtrack` via **mod_proxy**.

First generate/purchase the certificate for new domain `youtrack.example.com`. Then add this entry in your config.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName youtrack.example.com

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile    /your/ssl/public/path/mailserver.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /your/ssl/private/path/mailserver.pem

    ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/youtrack/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8080/youtrack/

</VirtualHost>
```

More info: [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension)

Comment: This loads the HTML I want to see, but all links are prefixed with `/youtrack` eg. `example.com/youtrack/login` instead of `example.com/login`

Comment: There are two possibilities in above problem, either you use (1) [mod_substitute](http://serverfault.com/questions/366662/solution-for-reverse-proxying-onto-urls-that-are-not-amenable-to-being-relocated) or (2) you find out how to change the youtrack BaseURL

Comment: `mod_substitute` won't work in this case, as the prefix affects not only the HTML code. I change the youtrack url in `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh` adding `-Djetbrains.youtrack.baseUrl=` to JAVA_OPTS.

Comment: Everything works ok under `youtrack.example.com/youtrack/`. How to get rid the trailing path? The app is currently deployed on `/youtrack` path. I'd probably need `/` instead, but I don't know how to change it in Tomcat.

Comment: Maybe related to this issue [Base URL couldn't be applied if it's passed as a Java parameter](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-21648?_ga=1.57297002.116128773.1398266183) and [little discussion here](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/YouTrack-1159)

Comment: Still not working. Maybe I can set up the subdomain using Tomcat instead of the Apache proxy?

Comment: Maybe that solution will work. Unfortunately I have no experience with Tomcat. If you can setup subdomain via Tomcat, then change`ProxyPass`  and `ProxyPassReverse` parameter in my answer become `/ http://youtrack.example.com:8080/`